# Cyrillic letters encoded wrong using model.matrix

Tags: r, encoding, cyrillic, model.matrix

I have a data frame containing cyrillic (Russian) letters in both of the column names and values that need to be transformed using model.matrix.

model.matrix transforms these variables into unicode characters such as . Is there any way to convert them back, or avoid the conversion in the first place?

```
library(tibble)
x <- tribble(~"тест", ~value1, ~value2,
         "тест", 5, 10,
         "тест2", 6, 11)
m <- model.matrix(value1 ~ ., data = x)
```

The expected result is a model.matrix containing the characters in UTF-8 as they should be.

Comment: it could be a locale settting issue

Comment: Sounds like you're using Windows.  Windows doesn't support UTF-8 locales, so things often get messed up there.  In a UTF-8 locale, your code looks fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved using `stringi`:

```
library(stringi)
colnames(m) <- stri_unescape_unicode(gsub("<U\\+(....)>",
                                    "\\\\u\\1",
                                    colnames(m)))
```